# Register made in PHP and AJAX not working

Tags: php, ajax, phonegap

Basically, I made a login/register with PHP and Ajax to work with phonegap. The login works, if I try to create an account with the same email as an existing one, it responds, but when I try to create a new account, it says registration failed.~
Above there is the code

PHP code

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "login") or die("connection error");
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if(isset($_POST['register']))
{   
    $register = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'"));
    if($register == 0)
    {
        $insert = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO users (email,password) VALUES ('$email','$password')");
        if($insert)                 
            echo "success";
        else
            echo "error";
    }
    else if($register != 0)
        echo "exist";
}
else if(isset($_POST['login']))
{
    $login = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password`='$password'"));
    if($login != 0)
        echo "success";
    else
        echo "error";
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

AJAX code
 // this is login code

```
$("#loginButton").click(function(){
            var email= $.trim($("#email").val());
            var password= $.trim($("#password").val());

            $("#status").text("Authenticating...");
            var loginString ="email="+email+"&password="+password+"&login=";
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",crossDomain: true, cache: false,
                url: url,
                data: loginString,
                success: function(data){
                    if(data == "success") {
                        $("#status").text("Login Success..!");
                        localStorage.loginstatus = "true";
                        window.location.href = "app.html";
                    }
                    else if(data == "error")
                    {
                        $("#status").text("Login Failed..!");
                    }
                }
            });
        });

   $("#registerButton").click(function(){
            var email= $.trim($("#email").val());
            var password= $.trim($("#password").val());

            $("#status").text("Creating New Account...");
            var dataString="email="+email+"&password="+password+"&register=";
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",crossDomain: true, cache: false,
                url: url,
                data: dataString,
                success: function(data){
                    if( data == "success")
                        $("#status").text("Registered Success");
                    else if( data == "exist")
                        $("#status").text("Account is already there");
                    else if( data == "error")
                        $("#status").text("Register Failed");
                }
            });
```

Comment: where is url to php file, i guess you are missing that in ajax?

Comment: $(document).ready(function() { var url = "http://localhost/StudyBuddy/StudyBuddy/www/auth.php";~

Comment: It's on the start of the code, didn't post all because it has the login too and that is working

Comment: ok then what about &register=? in dataString, have you checked console errors?

Comment: idk how to see the console, how it is?

Comment: can you please share the  $("#loginButton").click(function(){
if using google chrome, use developer tools to identify client side js errors.(you may have one) 
pressing SHIFT + CTRL + I will open developer tools then console

Comment: right click on the webpage and then click inspect there you can find console for js errors

Comment: @Ali It's on the post

Comment: I got no java script, only ajax and php http://prntscr.com/lt12dz

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have internet access permission enabled in config.xml

Answer (score -1):

it took me a good time to find out the issue. and it is very simple mistake, check your SELECT query for syntax error.

> 1 queries executed, 0 success, 1 errors, 0 warnings
>
> Query: SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='ali@akashif.co.uk' AND
>   password`='123'
>
> Error Code: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '`='123'

there is an extra ` after the password which is breaking the query. and query is failing resulting  mysqli_num_rows to always return 0.